# Why "that" not "when"?

Tags: parsing

The original sentence:

> Those who believe in capital punishment may have arguments for its
>   retention, but surely no reasonable argument can be found for
>   retention of the sickening mumbo-jumbo that accompanies **it** from the
>   moment that the judge dons the black cap with what looks like a
>   pen-wiper balanced on the top of his wig, to the reading of the burial
>   service over the condemned man before he is dead.

Three questions:

1. Does **'it'** refer to '**capital punishment**'?
2. Is "**that accompanies it from the moment that the judge dons the black cap with what looks like a pen-wiper balanced on the top of his wig**" the restrictive attributive clause for "**the sickening mumbo-jumbo**"? If so, which syntactical function does "**that**" serve in the dependent attributive clause? It's kind of hard to understand it as an adverbial of time in this case.
3. Is it fine to replace "that" with "when"?

> Those who believe in capital punishment may have arguments for its
>   retention, but surely no reasonable argument can be found for
>   retention of the sickening mumbo-jumbo that accompanies it from the
>   moment **when** the judge dons the black cap with what looks like a
>   pen-wiper balanced on the top of his wig, to the reading of the burial
>   service over the condemned man before he is dead.

Comment: Yes, it's a restrictive attributive / adjective clause. *That* is just a relative pronoun. You can replace it with *when* but it flows better with *that* in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry I've just re-read your question and see you asked whether *that accompanies...* is a  restrictive attributive clause for *the sickening mumbo-jumbo*. It's not - it relates to *the moment*.

Comment: @Minty, thanks. Could you re-order the sentence to make it easier to comprehend please.

Comment: It seems to be in a logical order already - from time A to time B, where A is *the moment that the judge dons the black cap* and B is *the reading of the burial service*. It's the extra information that is given that makes it more complicated. We are told that when the judge dons the black cap, he has something that looks like a pen-wiper balanced on the top of his wig, and the burial service is described as being read *over* the condemned man before he is dead. If you want to simplify it, I would take those things out first.

Comment: It's a pretty convoluted sentence. Possibly useful for analysis, but you wouldn't want to talk that way.